# Java opening socket streams in both ways

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I want to make a game (jungle speed), where players click totem and it changes position on screen (I'm using swing, it's not important) and information about localisation change should be sent to everyone.

I want to make a server which gets player's click, verifies it and send update info to all.
In this scenario, client listens to server if someone has clicked totem and meanwhile is ready to send info about his own click.
Server listens to everyone and meanwhile is ready to send information to all.
I try to implement it like this:
Server generates thread for each player, listens inside for click and is ready to be interrupted to send new totem localisation (I use method shutdownNow on ExecutorService, which should cause IOException in threads which will made them to stop doing loop and send information about new localisation) then client-side gets it.
Same for client side if he clicks, thread is interrupted and instead of waiting for new localisation it sends his click.

The problem is that I can't create streams. Here is output and code

Client side:

```
2017-05-22T23:04:06.417Connected
2017-05-22T23:04:06.417Trying to make output
2017-05-22T23:04:06.417Trying to make input
```

Server side:

```
2017-05-22T23:04:03.278Server Thread :Socket created
2017-05-22T23:04:03.294Server Thread :Waiting for client!
2017-05-22T23:04:06.385Server Thread :Correct, connected!
2017-05-22T23:04:12.239Trying to make input
```

Client side code :

```
package client;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class ServerConnection implements Runnable {

    MainWindow frame;
    Socket toServ;
    Socket fromServ;
    ServerSocket myServ;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream reader;
    public int x, y, totemx, totemy;
    int i = 0;

    public ServerConnection(MainWindow frame) {
        try {
            this.frame = frame;
            myServ = new ServerSocket(1338);
            toServ = new Socket("localhost", 1337);
            fromServ = myServ.accept();
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Connected");
            try {
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Trying to make output");
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(toServ.getOutputStream()));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Trying to make input");
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fromServ.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Running");

        while (true) {
            try {
                int xGot, yGot;
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Waiting for params");
                xGot = (int) reader.readInt();
                yGot = (int) reader.readInt();
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "I got new params");
                frame.refresh(xGot, yGot);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Sending click thread: Sending my click");
                        out.writeInt(x);
                        out.writeInt(y);
                        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Sent");
                    } catch (IOException ex1) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ServerConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server side code
First file:

```
package javaapplicationserwer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Japko
 */
public class Server{

    public int x, y;
    ServerSocket serv = null;
    ExecutorService executor;
    Server()
    {
        x = 10;
        y = 50;
         executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        try {
            serv = new ServerSocket(1337);
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Server Thread :Socket created");
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Server Thread :Waiting for client!");
                Socket fromSocket = serv.accept();
                Socket toSocket=new Socket(fromSocket.getInetAddress(),1338);
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Server Thread :Correct, connected!");
                ClientConnection temp = new ClientConnection(fromSocket,toSocket, this);
                executor.submit(temp);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplicationSerwer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void updateIt(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Updating");
        if (x == this.x && y == this.y) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            this.x = rand.nextInt(300);
            this.y = rand.nextInt(300);
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Updated");
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "I notify");
    }
}
```

Second file (Class implementing runnable which is created for each player by server):

```
package javaapplicationserwer;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ClientConnection implements Runnable {

    Socket fromSocket, toSocket;
    InetAddress IP;
    Server serv;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream reader;

    public ClientConnection(Socket fromSocket, Socket toSocket, Server serwer) {
        this.fromSocket = fromSocket;
        this.toSocket = toSocket;
        this.serv = serwer;
        try {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Trying to make input");
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fromSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Trying to make output");
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(toSocket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Starting");
            try {
                int xGot, yGot;
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Waiting for params");
                    try {
                        xGot = reader.readInt();
                        yGot = reader.readInt();
                        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Got this");
                        //serv.wait();
                        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Waited");
                        serv.updateIt(xGot, yGot);
                        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Verified");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        try {
                            out.writeInt(serv.x);
                            out.writeInt(serv.y);
                        } catch (IOException ex1) {
                            Logger.getLogger(ClientConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
                        }
                        Logger.getLogger(ClientConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }
            } finally {
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "I'm not serving for you");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It sounds like client has mate output (which means that server has input), then client wants to create input, but server escapes from constructor and doesn't even try to make its output.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Have you tried adding `out.flush()` after the write calls?  Also, what does your println debugging show?

Comment: 'Can't create streams' is not a problem description, and neither is 'escapes from constructor'.

Comment: @Gray out.flush() helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

out.flush() helped in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are a two (2) way connection. You only need one socket in the client connection.

here is some code that does simple tcp:

```
package p;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.function.*;
public class Tcp {
    static class Acceptor extends Thread {
        Acceptor(ServerSocket serverSocket,Consumer<Socket> consumer) {
            super("Acceptor");
            this.serverSocket=serverSocket;
            this.consumer=consumer;
        }
        @Override public void run() {
            p("acceptor running on: "+serverSocket);
            while(true)
                try {
                    Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
                    if(consumer!=null) consumer.accept(socket);
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    p(getName()+" caught: "+e);
                    break;
                }
        }
        final ServerSocket serverSocket;
        final Consumer<Socket> consumer;
    }
    static class Connection implements Runnable {
        Connection(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            this.socket=socket;
            in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out=new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        boolean send(String string) {
            try {
                p("sending: "+string+" on: "+socket);
                out.write(string+'\n'/*System.getProperty("line.separator")*/);
                out.flush();
                return true;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
        void process(String string) {
            p("connection on: "+socket+" received: "+string);
        }
        @Override public void run() {
            p("connection on: "+socket+" is runing.");
            String string=null;
            try {
                p("connection on: "+socket+" is trying to read.");
                while((string=in.readLine())!=null) {
                    process(string);
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            process(null);
            p("connection on: "+socket+" is exiting run()");
        }
        final Socket socket;
        final BufferedReader in;
        final Writer out;
    }
    public static void p(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    Tcp(String host,Integer service) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket();
        SocketAddress socketAddress=new InetSocketAddress(host,service);
        serverSocket.bind(socketAddress);
        Consumer<Socket> socketConsumer=(socket)-> {
            p("accepted from: "+socket);
            try {
                final Connection connection=new Connection(socket) {
                    @Override void process(String string) {
                        super.process(string);
                        send(string.toUpperCase());
                    }
                };
                new Thread(connection,"incoming").start();
            } catch(IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        new Acceptor(serverSocket,socketConsumer).start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,IOException,InterruptedException {
        final String host="localhost";
        final Integer service=1237;
        Tcp tcp=new Tcp(host,service);
        Socket socket=new Socket(host,service);
        Connection c1=new Connection(socket);
        new Thread(c1,"c1").start();
        socket=new Socket(host,service);
        Connection c2=new Connection(socket);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        new Thread(c2,"c2").start();
        c1.send("foo");
        c2.send("bar");
    }
}
```

Comment: As I read i can't have input and output stream in the time. Am I wrong? I had a version with one socket, still didn't work.

Comment: @JakubJabłoński As you read *where*? Where on earth did you read this rubbish?